# trying to figure out how to set up polar area given two equations

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, area

$R=3$ and $R=4-2sin(\theta)$

Find the area

I got the second part of the equation right ($1/2$ the integration of $\pi/6$ to $5\pi/6$ of $(4-2sin(x))^2)$ but he first part confuses me. The answer key stated that there was a $6\pi$ added out in front and they got $6\pi$ from $2/3\pi(3^2)$. where did these numbers come from?

Comment: Your post should identify clearly the *region* whose area we want to find. Then answers can be given. Inside both curves? Outside the circle but inside the other curve?

Comment: I apologize. The bounds are from pi/6 to 5pi/6. I needed the region enclosed within the cardiod and circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3=4-2\sin\theta\implies \theta=\arcsin\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{6},\dfrac{5\pi}{6}$. Inside both curves, we have:
$$A=\int^{5\pi/6}_{\pi/6}\dfrac{1}{2}\left((4-2\sin\theta)^2-3^2\right)d\theta$$
Now,
$$\dfrac{9}{2}\int^{5\pi/6}_{\pi/6}d\theta=\dfrac{9}{2}\left(\dfrac{5\pi-\pi}{6}\right)=\\
\dfrac{9}{2}\times\dfrac{2\pi}{3}=3\pi$$
Hope this helps,

Comment: ok thank you for your help! One quick question. Can you tell me where you got the arcsin from?

Comment: @sloth1111 $$-1=-2\sin \theta\\ \implies \sin \theta=1/2\\ \implies \theta=\arcsin \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$$

Comment: oh ok gotcha. ill keep that in mind when i do the next one